# Ошибка: error C1083: Не удается открыть файл включение: d3dx9.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++

Как исправить ошибку:

```
error C1083: Не удается открыть файл включение: d3dx9.h: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В коде ошибки написано, что компилятор не нашел `"d3dx9.h". Попробуй в директории include своей IDE посмотреть есть ли данный заголовочный файл, или попробуй вложить его в текущую директорию проекта.

Comment: А ещё установите DirectX SDK, если не ставили ранее.